# excel function for stock system

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a store and a shipping container storage unit.
I have boxes that I can either store in the store itself or in the container. 
I have developed a spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image: stock screenshot]

I want to be able to set a number of total stock in the '**B**' column which will be split between the '**D**' column and the '**F**' Column

I don't want the sum of the '**D**' column plus the '**F**' column to be able to go above the number in the '**B**' column

I also want the '**D**' column and the '**F**' column to be reactive so it I change the number in one the other adapts to make sure the sum is still equal to the '**B**' column

I'm not asking for someone to do this for me or free of charge but I'd really appreciate some help in the right direction as to the functions I'd need to use etc.

Comment: If you are planning to edit Columns B, D, or F, then you won't find a solution with a formula because at some point you will overwrite it and then your system will fail. I'd create a user form with a drop down menu containing Column A with input boxes for your other three columns. The user form would have a button that you use to confirm a change and a VBA procedure updates the cells appropriately. Are you familiar with user forms or VBA?

Comment: @ChristopherD., good points.  Actually, this wouldn't even require VBA if there is a separate input form.  It could just check for which value needs calculating.

Comment: Aaron, what you describe in the question is just using Excel to do simple subtraction.  You don't describe any kind of optimization or decision-making that you expect Excel to do.  You enter a total and a value for one of the locations (which you determine yourself), and the spreadsheet subtracts and posts the remainder for the other location.  With Christopher D.'s suggestion, you just have to stick an IF test in each location.  If the input form has a value for the location, display that.  If not, display the remainder.